# mobile application performance testing tools

Tags: jquery, html, devexpress, cordova, performance-testing

Is there any open source mobile application performance testing tools available ??
please suggest me 2-3 name and link.

note: My application is based on dxtreme.(HTML JS cross plateform application which uses phonegap api)

Thanks and regards,
Rudresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the built-in (free) Google Chrome dev toolbar features for this purpose,

- see the [Profiling JavaScript performance](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling) article for more information.

If you are interested in deeper research of the critical bottlenecks,

- take a look at the 
  [JavaScript Performance Best Practices](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#JavaScript_Performace_Best_Practices) guidance.

Answer (score 3):

For android you have Little Eye http://www.littleeye.co/ to analyse the application performance, but not free of cost. it provides 30 days trail version. its really a great tool if you look for android application performance.

Answer (score 2):

plz try with this:

1. [Monkeytalk](http://gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk) cross platform (android, Ios, Windows, html5 applications)
2. [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) (for android)

Comment: I asked for open source brother. I will be glad to get name of open source mobile application performance testing tools.

Comment: monkey talk is free and open souece tool

Comment: Monkey tool is not. I contacted them and they said it would cost around $5000 per month.